# href link either by using Xpath Or CSS

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on the "Automation Practise-2 link" using "Href Attributes" either by  "XPATH" or "CSS" as well tried all the possible way but still not working. Images are attached.
Help will be really appreciated.

[image]

[image]

```
 <a _ngcontent-myb-c2 href="https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/">Automation Practise - 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used not only a clear path, but also combine them, or search by part of the query.
For example, the contents property can search for part of the text in a link.
1) `my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Automation Practise - 2')]").click()` or
2) `my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'AutomationPractice')]").click()`

Try this solution